# What happens at T-0 for the SpaceX Starship?

Tags: spacex-starship, launch-sequence

Every launch system [defines a different event for T-0](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19232/what-actually-happens-at-t-minus-0). The SpaceX Starship prototypes seem to ignite the engines at T-1.0 and accent seems to begin between T+1.0 and T+1.5. An overthrust abort for SN-10 was declared at T-0.1. So what defines the T-0 time for Starship?

Comment: I believe it is when they release the hold down clamps, just like F9. But I don't think there has ever been any official confirmation of that. It is also not clear whether that is even the same for each launch, since they are still developing the processes just as they are still developing the vehicle.