# What specific event determined the "end" of a shuttle mission?

Tags: space-shuttle, landing, time

We've had [several](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19232/26446) [questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17774/26446) [about](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36211/26446) when a mission officially "begins".  But what about when a mission officially "ends"?

The [Apollo Flight Journal](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/) stops the mission clock at splashdown.  **What was the official "end of mission" event for the Shuttle?**  Did it involve one or more of the following?

- Touchdown -- the Shuttle equivalent of splashdown
- The Shuttle has rolled to a stop
- The last astronaut exits the spacecraft
- Authority is transferred from Houston to Kennedy
- The mission clock is stopped
- Recordings and logs stop

Comment: I suspect this is tautological: "end of mission" as defined by who, for what purpose? Touchdown time (which is what FAI records care about) is touchdown time. Wheel stop time is wheel stop time. Mission clock stop time is mission clock stop time, etc.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Certainly, one could pick any of these events to call the end-of-mission.  Just like there are several events proximal to launch which *could have* been chosen as T=0.  But *something* was officially picked for T=0.  Was something similarly designated as the end?

Comment: From whose perspective @DrSheldon? NASA brass may have one definition whereas mission control may have another.

Comment: @GdD I'm willing to bet all my SpaceX stock :-)  that there is a specific definition for end of a mission and thus when the mission clock is stopped.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, that doesn't seem the be the question.

Comment: Shuttle missions had an official length so there was obviously an official event that ended them. I just need to find it written down once I get out of bed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Flight Durations are determined from the time of liftoff to MLG
> Touchdown, specified in days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

MLG = Main Landing Gear

[Space Shuttle Missions Summary](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110001406/downloads/20110001406.pdf) page 1-2

STS-1 example:

Liftoff 102:12:00:03.9 MLGTD 104:18:20:57 gives 2:06:20:53.1 which you'll see as the flight duration [everywhere](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/shuttlemissions/archives/sts-1.html) (usually w/o the .1)

For STS-51-L and STS-107 "flight duration" stopped when contact was lost.

Comment: It should be noted that there were tons of ways for a crew member to "become famous" after MLG touchdown. The post-wheelstop procedures were quite involved, lengthy, and tedious for the folks on the flight deck...personally, I didn't really heave a sigh of relief until I was back in the Astro Van, hydrating.